# How does closing jdbc sqlconnection work?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

In the following code block, I expected the connection to be closed synchronously before SQL query is being executed asynchronously but evidently SQL connection refuses to be closed until the query finishes executing.

```
public static Future<List<JsonObject>> queryExecuter(JDBCClient jdbcClient, int id,String type) {
    Promise<List<JsonObject>> promise = Promise.promise();
    
    jdbcClient.getConnection(sqlConnection->{
        if(sqlConnection.succeeded()) {
            DTOQueryInfo dtoQueryInfo = queryHelper(sqlConnection.result(), id, type);
            //Execute query 
            sqlConnection.result().queryWithParams(dtoQueryInfo.getSqlString(), dtoQueryInfo.getParams(), fetchSequenceResult->{
                if (fetchSequenceResult.succeeded()) {
                    
                    if (fetchSequenceResult.result()==null || fetchSequenceResult.result().getRows()==null || fetchSequenceResult.result().getRows().isEmpty()) {       
                        logger.info("Query with no result ");
                        promise.fail("Failed!");
                    }else {
                        logger.info("Query Result:{} ", fetchSequenceResult.result().getRows());
                        promise.complete(fetchSequenceResult.result().getRows());
                    }
                } else {
                    logger.error("Unable to inquiryActions  :{}", fetchSequenceResult.cause());
                    promise.fail(new WSEXCP_NoAccessDefinedToNode(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(101)+String.valueOf(941)), "خطای داخلی. لطفا با راهبر سامانه تماس بگیرید.", HttpStatusEnum.SERVER_ERROR.getMin()));
                }

            });
        }
        else {
            logger.error("خطای اتصال به دیتابیس : ", sqlConnection.cause());
            promise.fail("خطای اتصال به دیتابیس");
        }
        sqlConnection.result().close();
    });
    return promise.future();
}
```

```
I tried increasing query execution time by Thread.sleep and then query executed successfully then sqlConnection.close() execute.
```

Comment: Umm, why do you want to close connection *before* it's finished executing? This is like pulling a rug from under someone standing on it, you might have seen in in disney cartoons

Comment: What is this `JDBCClient` library you're using?

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that the connection is closed after the query execution, you should move the close statement inside the queryWithParams callback.

```
public static Future<List<JsonObject>> queryExecuter(JDBCClient jdbcClient, int id, String type) {
    Promise<List<JsonObject>> promise = Promise.promise();

    jdbcClient.getConnection(sqlConnection -> {
        if (sqlConnection.succeeded()) {
            DTOQueryInfo dtoQueryInfo = queryHelper(sqlConnection.result(), id, type);
            // Execute query 
            sqlConnection.result().queryWithParams(dtoQueryInfo.getSqlString(), dtoQueryInfo.getParams(), fetchSequenceResult -> {
                if (fetchSequenceResult.succeeded()) {

                    if (fetchSequenceResult.result() == null || fetchSequenceResult.result().getRows() == null || fetchSequenceResult.result().getRows().isEmpty()) {
                        logger.info("Query with no result ");
                        promise.fail("Failed!");
                    } else {
                        logger.info("Query Result:{} ", fetchSequenceResult.result().getRows());
                        promise.complete(fetchSequenceResult.result().getRows());
                    }

                } else {
                    logger.error("Unable to inquiryActions  :{}", fetchSequenceResult.cause());
                    promise.fail(new WSEXCP_NoAccessDefinedToNode(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(101) + String.valueOf(941)), "خطای داخلی. لطفا با راهبر سامانه تماس بگیرید.", HttpStatusEnum.SERVER_ERROR.getMin()));
                }

                // Close the connection here, after the query execution
                sqlConnection.result().close();
            });
        } else {
            logger.error("خطای اتصال به دیتابیس : ", sqlConnection.cause());
            promise.fail("خطای اتصال به دیتابیس");
        }
    });

    return promise.future();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but now how it works? by chance?